# Heroku getting at=error code=H10 while deploying python Flask web app

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first flask application in heroku. Followed steps exactly as mentioned in heroku documentation. But It is throwing Application error as shown below

```
2021-07-18T12:55:34.315320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=eflask-simple-app.herokuapp.com request_id=30d3a699-6f05-4783-a5f5-40c9717af881 fwd="117.213.244.13" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

---

**Project Structure**

```
app
    main.py
Pipfile
Pipfile.lock
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
wsgi.py
```

**wsgi.py file**

```
from app.main import app
import os 

port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app
```

**app/main.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home_view():
        return "<h1>Welcome to Flask</h1>"
```

**requirements.txt**

```
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.9.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow @vishnuvreddy

Since you are deciding port using

```
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
```

and mentioned `--bind` in Procfile as below

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app
```

conflict each other.

**Solution**

Change Procfile to

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```